# Get text characters frame on UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I've a `ULabel` on my view controller. So, If user draws line over the `UILabel` then I've to print text from the `UILabel` by user drawn range. This is the purpose.

My question is,

How to get character frames from the `CGPoint` ranges (start & end) on `UILabel?` I simply want to print the string as I coded.

**Diagram:**

**Drawing:**

[image]

**String Range:**

[image]

I don't have any clue to solve this problem. So, Please help to find the solution. Thanks in advance...

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .medium)
    
    lazy var label: UILabel = {
    
        let label =  UILabel()
        label.text = "The orange is the fruit of various citrus"
        label.font  = font
        label.textAlignment = .left
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
         ])
        return label
    }()
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        let button = UIButton(frame: .init(x: (view.frame.width/2)-30, y: 80, width: 60, height: 40))
        button.backgroundColor = .gray
        button.setTitle("Print", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        
    }
    
    @objc func actionButton(){
        
        //Any demo points.
        let p1 = CGPoint.zero
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: 70, y: 0)
        
        print("String: ")
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you would use a UITextView, because that uses Text Kit very directly, and Text Kit knows exactly what characters are at each point.

Comment: @matt, Ok thanks for that. I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Swift Playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabelExtended()
        label.frame = view.bounds
        label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book."
        label.textColor = .black
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
    
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()

class UILabelExtended: UILabel {
    
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: .zero)
    var textStorage = NSTextStorage()
    lazy var gesture = TouchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSwipe(gesture:)))
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    override var text: String? {
        get {
            return super.attributedText?.string
        }
        set {
            let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.font: font!]
            attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: newValue ?? "", attributes: attrs)
            updateTextContainer()
        }
    }
    
    var startIndex = -1
    var endIndex = -1
    var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var endPoint = CGPoint.zero
    
    @objc func onSwipe(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            updateBoundingBox()
            let start = getTextIndexFrom(point: gesture.location(in: self))
            startIndex = start.0
            startPoint = start.1
        case .changed:
            let end = getTextIndexFrom(point: gesture.location(in: self))
            endIndex = end.0
            endPoint = end.1
                
            if let text = attributedText?.string, startIndex > -1 {
                if startIndex > endIndex { swap(&startIndex, &endIndex) }
                let s = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: startIndex)
                let e = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: endIndex)
                print(startPoint, endPoint, text[s...e])
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    var textBoundingBox: CGRect = .zero
    private func updateBoundingBox() {
        textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        textBoundingBox.origin = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - textBoundingBox.size.width / 2, y: bounds.midY - textBoundingBox.size.height / 2)
    }
    
    private func getTextIndexFrom(point: CGPoint) -> (Int, CGPoint) {
        let touchPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: point.y - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
        let index = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: touchPoint, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        return (index, touchPoint)
    }
    
    private func updateTextContainer() {
        textStorage = .init(attributedString: attributedText!)
        
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainer.size = bounds.size
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(2)
            context.move(to: startPoint)
            context.addLine(to: endPoint)
            
            context.addRect(textBoundingBox)
            
            context.strokePath()
            
        }
    }
}

class TouchGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override init(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
        delegate = self
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        state = .began
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        state = .changed
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        state = .ended
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        state = .cancelled
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return !(otherGestureRecognizer is TouchGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Perfectly working. Great, Thank your for your solution. It's helps me lot.. Thank you!